# Replace one div with another div using dynamically created content

Tags: php, jquery

So what I have is a php script that queries a database, and creates a number of  elements which display both a red team abbreviation, and a blue team abbreviation (much like the schedule strip on the top of nfl.com).  I am trying to acoomplish the following:

On mouse hover of a game element (class=game), swap out the div layer with one that contains the date and time of the match.

What I am having trouble with is somehow relating the two items together within jQuery.  I can get jQuery to know what item it needs to hide, but not what item it needs to replace it with.

```
$db = get_database_connection();

$today = date("Y-m-d");

$sql='
SELECT game_date as date,
        game_time as time,
                stred.team_name AS redteam,
                stblue.team_name AS blueteam,
                stred.team_abbreviation as redteamabbrev,
                stblue.team_abbreviation as blueteamabbrev
FROM stats_tblGames
INNER JOIN stats_tblTeams AS stred ON stats_tblGames.fk_id_team_red = stred.id_team
INNER JOIN stats_tblTeams AS stblue ON stats_tblGames.fk_id_team_blue = stblue.id_team
ORDER BY date ASC
LIMIT 5
';

echo '<div class="switch">';

foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {

$date = $row['date'];

if($today > $date) {

    $time = date('g:i A T',($row['time']));
    $redteam = $row['redteamabbrev'];
    $blueteam = $row['blueteamabbrev'];

    $control = $date . $redteam;
    $control2 = $redteam . $date;

    # Convert date
    $format = date_format(new DateTime($date), 'D, M j');    

    echo "<div id='$control' class='game'>";

        echo '<strong class="red-team">' . $redteam . '</strong><br>';
        echo '<strong class="blue-team">' . $blueteam . '</strong>';

    echo '</div>';

    echo "<div id='$control2' class='game hide'>";

        echo '<strong>' . $format . '</strong><br>';
        echo '<strong>' . $time . '</strong>';

    echo '</div>';

    # Script to hide/show games on hover
}
}

echo '</div>';

echo '<p class="clearfix"></p>';

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery('.game').mouseover(function() {
    jQuery(this.id).hide();
    jQuery(this.id).closest(SHOWID).show();            
});

</script>
```

Comment: replace `jQuery(this.id)` with `$(this)`

Comment: You're missing the all important [**`document.ready()`**](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

Comment: @MackieeE Why would he need that?

Comment: @MackieeE The `.game` element clearly exists already. All that putting that code into a document.ready handler would do is make the mouseover start working a little later than it should.

Comment: You guys are missing the point.  The point is that I'm trying to relate the two divs somehow so that I am able to use jQuery to hide/show them.  Currently I cannot figure out a way to get the ID of the hidden div so that jQuery can use it

Comment: You can probably use higher z-index for the hidden div just remember to switch back when toggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making the two divs children of the game class?

```
<div class='game'>
    <div id='$control'></div>
    <div id='$control2' class='hide'></div>
</div>
```

which should allow you to use something like

```
jQuery('.game').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children().toggle();    
});

jQuery('.game').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children().toggle();    
});
```

(which would also work without the $control/$control2 id's)

See http://jsfiddle.net/y3wLsz35/2/ for a working example

Comment: That's not what I am having trouble with though (unless I am greatly misunderstanding your post).  I am having trouble getting the id of the hidden div so that I am able to show it when the shown div is hovered upon.  $control1 and $control2 dynamically change by the way, they are all differnet IDs

Comment: ah, I see what you mean now... then I would suggest a slightly different approach... updating my answer...

Comment: I see what you did, but because $control and $control2 are variables created through the combination of data and team abbreviation (each game element has a differnet id) it won't work

Comment: By using .children() the id's become irrelevant. Check http://jsfiddle.net/y3wLsz35/2/ using mouseenter/mouseleave instead of mouseover makes sure the toggle doesn't keep firing while your mouse pointer hovers over the div.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea this was possible.  Thanks a ton for your help, and for the working example :)